# Is there a way to scroll web page using mouse wheel with Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to read contents of the website using selenium, to read the whole web page, I have to scroll down to the bottom of the page.
But scroll is only possible using mouse wheel.

I have tried all the answers mentioned in the previous similarly asked question but none of the solutions worked.
I have tried sending PageDown and End keys to the html and body element,
I have tried to execute window.scroll script using driver.execute and element.execute

It would be really helpful, If someone can help me demonstrate mouse scrolling using selenium Python

Comment: This should be 2 questions: 1) can you trigger wheel mouse events using javascript? and 2) can you execute arbitrary javascript using selenium? I guess both questions already have good answers in this site.

Comment: @PauloScardine I will keep that in mind, To break question if possible to granularity and simplicity.

Comment: @PauloScardine I tried running some javascript code mentioned in one of answers that you might be referring to. Hence posted this question mentioning that I tried all the answers.

Comment: It is hard to give advice without replicating the problem. Can you share what website we are talking about?

Comment: @PauloScardine Due to compliance,I cannot
Also just putting out that I tried most common answer given below, but that doesn't work either
`driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")`

Comment: Possible solution to manage this, I can think of is keep the selenium driver always in focus using pywinauto and pass mouse scroll commands using pynput.

But this solution is very eccentric and It will be hard to deploy in production

Comment: Instead of `window.scrollTo` try to dispatch a `new WheelEvent(0, {deltaX: 0, deltaY: 200}))`. Check the documentation on [WeelEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent)` and [Creating and triggering events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events).

Comment: @PauloScardine Didn't work

Comment: Sorry, it is a good question but I don't think we can really answer it without reverse engineering the site HTML/JS in order to figure out which mouse event is being used. Unless you can provide the real URL or an equivalent [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) your question is probably too broad for this site.

Comment: As stated earlier, cannot share the original URL due to compliance.
However I have found out that this [https://www.laphase5.com/](https://www.laphase5.com/) behaves same as the URL I am working on

Comment: We are volunteering to help here, please be kind! Ok, your real problem is reading the content, right? Seems like you are convinced that you need to scroll down in order to read it (it is not the case with the https://www.laphase5.com/, selenium can read the content without scrolling). BTW have you tried creating a very long browser window, lets say, 20,000 pixels of height (so there is no scroll)?

Comment: Hey Paulo, Pardon me if I have disrespected you or me was 
 a bit rash in any way.
I will try to create a long browser, Thanks